# Hadoop - Exposing SQL interface on collection of CSV files with variable columns

Tags: sql, csv, hadoop, hive

I am relatively new to Hadoop and understand that there are possibly hundreds of ways and tools to solve any given problem. I am looking for someone to walk me through the generally acceptable best practice approach to solve a problem which I am hoping is a relatively common scenario.

I have a number of CSV files being generated from a process which I don't control. The CSV files are related, but each CSV file might have a different set of columns in it. I am providing a made-up example of two files below, in real life there will be many thousands of files and potentially thousands of columns.

**FILE1**

```
#COL1, COL3, COL4
a1, c1, d1
a2,,d2
a3,c3,d3
```

**FILE2**

```
#COL1, COL2, COL4
a1, b1, d6
a5, b5,
a3,,
```

I would eventually like to expose some kind of a tabular view accessible via SQL/JDBC on this data, which will have a theoretical structure like:

```
#COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
a1,,c1,d1
a1,b1,,d6
a3,,c3,d3
a3,c3,,
a5,b5,,
```

**Key points are:**

1. I would like a simple process to be able to update the available columns as new ones are discovered in newer files.
2. I would not want to be penalized for performance if the users wants to analyze or work with only 10-20 columns at a time when the list of all columns across all files is in the thousands.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably only a partial answer, but I can at least address your data structure. If you are looking to store variable sized data in a SQL database (regardless of the DBMS) you would probably want a structure similar to this...

***Added Note***:
I would use the following primarily as a "staging phase" for the incoming data. There should be a final database/schema containing the tables which store the end-product, or sanitized, final form of the data. These tables should only be used to get the data into the system. From there, I would have processes (automated or otherwise) that copies or moves this interim data into the final tables while sanitizing, normalizing, and all-around cleaning and verifying it. This proposed idea is by no means meant to be the whole solution, just a means of addressing the problem of variable structure of input data.

You would want a primary "column lookup" table that would be used to specify column names. We will call it, simply, `column_names`:

```
CREATE TABLE column_names 
 (
  c_id INT,
  c_name VARCHAR(20),
  c_size INT
 );
```

A sample of the data would be like this:

```
 c_int   | c_name   | c_size
==============================
 1       | col1     | 10
 2       | col2     | 5
 3       | col3     | 20
 4       | f_name   | 25
 5       | l_name   | 25
```

We could add more fields, if you want, to provide more granularity in your field definitions (i.e. data types, nullable, etc...) or leave it as is above to provide a simple, generic structure. We just assume, and convert, all incoming data as string/varchar. This keeps it a bit more simple for now.

After that, you might want something to define, lets call it, your "import sessions".

```
CREATE TABLE import_session 
 (
  session_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  create_date TIMESTAMP
 );
```

Sample data:

```
 session_id   | create_date
=====================================
 11123        | 2015-02-15 15:33:21
```

Again, this could get more specific if you need, but the above should serve the purpose for an example.

Next we need the structure for your imports. This will allow for the possibility of reuse of structures that may be common. We'll just call it `import_struct`.

```
CREATE TABLE import_struct
 (
  struct_id INT
  c_id INT
 );
```

Sample data:

```
 struct_id   | c_id   
=======================
 122         | 5
 122         | 4
 122         | 1
 122         | 2
 37          | 1
 37          | 2
 37          | 3
```

This sample contains two structures: 122 and 37.

Finally, we need a data storage table

```
CREATE TABLE session_data
 (
  session_id INT,
  struct_id INT,
  session_recid INT,
  c_id INT,
  c_data VARCHAR(1000)
 );
```

A simple data import might then look like this:

```
 session_id   | struct_id   | session_recid   | c_id   | c_data
=================================================================================
 11123        | 122         | 1               | 5      | Smith
 11123        | 122         | 1               | 4      | John
 11123        | 122         | 1               | 1      | 5551235555
 11123        | 122         | 1               | 2      | 90210
 11123        | 122         | 2               | 5      | Lincoln
 11123        | 122         | 2               | 4      | Abe
 11123        | 122         | 2               | 1      | 5551235511
 11123        | 122         | 2               | 2      | 90210
 11123        | 122         | 3               | 5      | Washington
 11123        | 122         | 3               | 4      | George
 11123        | 122         | 3               | 1      | 5551239999
 11123        | 122         | 3               | 2      | 90210
```

Hopefully this design for the database can get you going on the correct direction for what you are trying to do. This is just a very basic, very generic way to structure your data. As mentioned a few times, you can get a lot more specific in the structure, you can also add more tables in there to make the relationships, and therefore the data integrity, much more robust and better scale-able. Though, this should get you started.

Comment: Hi! If I understood you correctly, you are proposing I store the data using key value pairs, correct? I assume you are not recommending doing the final analysis in this format? At some point I would have to go back to a columnar format for this data. Unfortunately, the data ingestion is continuous and I don't exactly have a point in time when further ingestion stops. I need my final columnar view of the data to keep getting updated as new data is ingested.

Comment: Depending upon your volume, you could have hourly, twice-daily, daily, etc... batch jobs that transforms your data. If you need it to be immediate you could even write it into a trigger on the session table. Do the initial imports as a transaction, then when the transaction is committed initialize the transform/sanitization.The last step of that would be to remove all of the data related to that finished session batch.